# Ubuntu "sort -k<n> <filename>" not working for all columns in file

Tags: 18.04

Overview:

Am running "Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS" under Windows 10 downloaded from:

```
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual
```

When I attempt to "sort -k " where "-k" is -k[123456]", I get mixed results:

- "-k[12]":  sort works as expected
- "-k[345]": sort does not occur
- "-k6: sort occurs on column 5 (vs column 6)

If I stage the same file running on a Cisco UCS based RHEL RHEL 7.7 (Maipo) server, all six sorts ("sort -k[123456] " work as on the designated column.

Have I encountered a bug in Ubuntu or do sorts need to be run differently on Ubuntu vs. RHEL?

Sample Sorts:

```
LAPTOP-MOQUDB6E:/tmp $ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

LAPTOP-MOQUDB6E:/tmp $ cat members          # {original file}
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands

LAPTOP-MOQUDB6E:/tmp $ sort -k2 members     # {"-k2": Colum_2 sort works as expected}
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz

LAPTOP-MOQUDB6E:/tmp $ sort -k5 members     # {"-k5": Col_5 sort doesn't work}
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz

LAPTOP-MOQUDB6E:/tmp $ sort -k6 members     # {"-k6": anomoly (sort occurs on Col_5)}
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is probably to do with the default locale for the two systems, specifically the collation weight of leading whitespace.

First, it is important to note that `sort` delimits on a *non-blank to blank transition* by default - **not** blank to non-blank. So when you have a columnar file that uses multiple whitespace characters for alignment, those extra alignment characters are considered to be part of the following field. You can see how this affects your results by adding the `--debug` flag.

*[NOTE: I'm going to use the C locale here, since it exhibits the behavior you are seeing and I don't know what your actual locale is]*

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort --debug -k5 file
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
                                   _____________________________________
________________________________________________________________________
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
                                      _____________________________________
___________________________________________________________________________
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands
                                            ________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
                                            ____________________________________
________________________________________________________________________________
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz
                                               _______________________
______________________________________________________________________
```

Here you can see that what's actually happening is that it **is** sorting on column 5, however once you take into account the leading whitespace, the result is that it sorts in order of most-to-least leading whitespace.

Likewise when you use `-k6`, it really is sorting on the 6th column, coincidentally however that gives the same order as an alphabetical sort on the column 5 geographical regions (just because *A*sia happens to be short and **N**orth_America is long)

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort --debug -k6 file
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands
                                                     _______________________
____________________________________________________________________________
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
                                                       _________________________
________________________________________________________________________________
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
                                                       _________________
________________________________________________________________________
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
                                                              _____________
___________________________________________________________________________
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz
                                                              ________
______________________________________________________________________
```

The simplest solution is given in the debug output:

```
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
```

i.e.

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort --debug -b -k5 file
sort: using simple byte comparison
00017  Jasmine     <tbd>     Disney_Princess     Asia           Desert_Sands
                                                 ___________________________
____________________________________________________________________________
00013  Snow        White     Disney_Princess     Europe         Enchanted_Forest
                                                 _______________________________
________________________________________________________________________________
00018  Jiminy      Cricket   Disney              Europe         Tuscon0y
                                                 _______________________
________________________________________________________________________
00019  Speedy      Gonzales  Cats_Meow           North_America  Guadalajara
                                                 __________________________
___________________________________________________________________________
00016  Wiley       Coyote    Roadrunner_Nemesis  North_America  La_Paz
                                                 _____________________
______________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging and observed if the 6 column file has only a single space between fields on each line, then "sort -k# [source_file]"  ("#": 1-6) works on both Ubuntu & RHEL for sorts performed on columns 1-6.  Same is true for sort using "sort -k#,# [source_file]" (ex: sort -k1,1 ..., sort -k2,2 ...... sort -k6,6 ...").

If the six column file has more than one [whitespace] character between fields on each line (ex: file has been aligned using "cat [source_file] | column -t > [target_file]"), then "sort -k# [target_file]"  ("#": 1-6) only works on RHEL for columns 1-6.

For Ubuntu, I observed "sort -k #[target_file]" worked for columns 1 and 2, did nothing for columns 3-5 and "sort -k6 [target_file]" ended up sorting on column 5.

For my utility, I ended up preconditioning the sort input file to have only a single space between fields and then retested on both RHEL & Ubuntu to insure I was getting the desired results.  Thanks everyone who took a look at this sort anomaly between the two OS types.